# better striping method php regex

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match-all

please help me strip the following more efficiently.

```
a href="/mv/test-1-2-3-4.vFIsdfuIHq4gpAnc.html"
```

the site I visit has a few of those, I would only need everything in between the two periods:

```
vFIsdfuIHq4gpAnc
```

I would like to use my current format and coding that works around the regex environment. Please help me tune up my following preg match line:

```
preg_match_all("(./(.*?).html)", $sp, $content);
```

Any kind of help I get on this is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance!

Here is my complete code

```
$dp = "http://www.cnn.com";

$sp = @file_get_contents($dp);
if ($sp === FALSE) {
    echo("<P>Error: unable to read the URL $dp.  Process aborted.</P>");
    exit();
}

preg_match_all("(./(.*?).html)", $sp, $content); 

foreach($content[1] as $surl) {
    $nctid = str_replace("mv/","",$surl);
    $nctid = str_replace("/","",$nctid);
   echo $nctid,'<br /><br /><br />';
```

the above is what I have been working on

Comment: It seems you are trying apply regular expressions to HTML, which usually doesn't end well. Parse the HTML-file instead (there are several extension for this, like `DOMDocument` and such).

Comment: @KingCrunch Well, if uses DomDocument to get the <a> elements, and a regex to get "everything between the two periods", I'd say regex is actually a very acceptable solution. DomDocument won't help you to get "everything between the two periods".

Comment: @BerryLangerak Yes, then it's fine, but in the example is `a href=`, what makes me assume, that the OP currently doesn't think this way.

Comment: I have tried DOM before and it doesn't do what I need in this case. I would prefer to stick with regex by all means, thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty okay, really. It's just that you don't want to match `.*?`, you want to match multiple characters that aren't a full stop, so you can use `[^.]+` instead.

```
$sp = 'a href="/mv/test-1-2-3-4.vFIsdfuIHq4gpAnc.html"';
preg_match_all( '/\.([^.]+).html/', $sp, $content );

var_dump( $content[1] );
```

The result that is printed:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "vFIsdfuIHq4gpAnc"
}
```

Here's an example of how to loop through all links:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.cnn.com';

$dom = new DomDocument( );
@$dom->loadHTMLFile( $url );

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'a' );

foreach( $links as $link ) {
    $href = $link->attributes->getNamedItem( 'href' );
    if( $href !== null ) {
        if( preg_match( '~mv/.*?([^.]+).html~', $href->nodeValue, $matches ) ) {
            echo "Link-id found: " . $matches[1] . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Berry, I have used this and it does not come back with the results I am looking for.

Comment: @thevoipman It works like a charm for me. I've added a small example.

Comment: For example, when I go to cnn.com, I would get a bunch of these: /mv/test-1-2-3-4.vFIsdfuIHq4gpAnc.html - how do I implement that within your examples?

Comment: @thevoipman Ah, so your question is not about matching a string, but rather how you can find all links that contain /mv/?

Comment: Yes that's correct, and also the some stripping afterwards... Sorry for the confussion.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I learn from seeing the examples and then applying it...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `explode()`:

```
$string = 'a href="/mv/test-1-2-3-4.vFIsdfuIHq4gpAnc.html"';
if(stripos($string, '/mv/')){
    $dots = explode('.', $string);
    echo $dots[(count($dots)-2)];
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. Within the html there are other links that ends with html as well. I just don't know how to strip out the ones that has /mv/ within it and then use your example to test. Please help.

Comment: If you are looping over html links, use like I made above with `stripos()`

Comment: hello, I have a learning curve therefore I do not know what you're talking about in regards to stripos()... can you please kindly give me a full example based on the regex code I have provided?

Comment: You have given me this above: $string = 'a href="/mv/test-1-2-3-4.vFIsdfuIHq4gpAnc.html"';

But there will be many of these that has /mv/ in it, please help me extract the ones with /mv/ only and get the strings I required. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

```
$exploded = explode('.', $sp);
$content = $exploded[1]; // string: "vFIsdfuIHq4gpAnc"
```

Comment: if more than two dots in string then ??

Comment: Well the OP is not being very clear how much dots will be in the string. At any rate, Mihai's answer is much better than mine.

Comment: There will be other links that has .html of course, but if it has mv/ in it, it should only have two dots to with

Comment: @KemalFadillah If the html has other links within it, how would you rectify that it will only pull hreft that has mv/ in it?

Answer (score 0):

even more simpler

```
$sp="/mv/test-1-2-3-4.vFIsdfuIHq4gpAnc.html";
$regex = '/\.(?P<value>.*)\./';
preg_match_all($regex, $sp, $content);
echo nl2br(print_r($content["value"], 1));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried your example, and it did not return just the string: vFIsdfuIHq4gpAnc - it gave me a bunch of pictures and extra codes that I do not need. Please let me know if I'm missing or didn't configure your code to fit with what I need?

Comment: this is the whole code
$sp="/mv/test-1-2-3-4.vFIsdfuIHq4gpAnc.html";
$regex = '/\.(?P<value>.*)\./';
preg_match_all($regex, $sp, $content);
echo nl2br(print_r($content["value"], 1));
you can also try to print full array 
echo nl2br(print_r($content,1));

Comment: For example, when I go to cnn.com, I would get a bunch of these: /mv/test-1-2-3-4.vFIsdfuIHq4gpAnc.html - how do I implement that within your examples?

Comment: if you are treating cnn.com content as a single string then it will not work load your page as a dom element like this
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('cnn.com');
and then get the specific html tag which contains data

Comment: This won't work because these html links does not have it's own unique element for me to pull... they are all simple html links and the ones I want to parse/strip out has /mv/ infront of it...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17742/discussion-between-devnegikec-and-thevoipman)